# newline prints as a string

Tags: python, python-requests, newline, file-writing

I'm a beginner at python and I've been following this tutorial for parsing data from web pages, but I ran into a slight problem... for some reason, whenever I try to add a newline to the end of a variable (and adding that variable to the 'records' list), it writes to the file ("newyorktimes_test.txt") as '\n' itself, not an actual newline. I know this has something to do with the 'records' list, I just don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.
(Also, don't mind the website that I'm testing out, I'm only using
 it for its format.)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/06/23/opinion/trumps-lies.html')
with open("newyorktimes_test.txt", "r+") as ny_times:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'short-desc'})
    records = []
    for result in results:
        date = str(result.find('strong').text[0:-1]) + ', 2017' + '\n'
        lie = str(result.contents[1][1:-2]) + '\n'
        explanation = str(result.contents[2].text) + '\n'
        url = str(result.find('a')['href']) + '\n'
        records.append((date, lie, explanation, url))
```

Comment: You're not actually writing anything to the file in the code shown.  Please post code that reproduces your error.

Comment: This example does not reproduce the error you described. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry everyone! I forgot to add some parts, I'll do it right now.

Comment: What is wrong exactly? `'\n'` is an actual newline."

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us enough code to find the problem, so here's my speculation:

Don't add `+ '\n'` at the end of everything. It's the garbage that nobody needs and it takes space and makes your program less readable. When you actually need to output your results, `print` function will take care of newlines (or there will be another, quite convenient method to add them). Save data **without** newlines.

Comment: So sorry about that, I forgot to add two lines of code (I'll do it right away). Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

There is no code for actually writing to the file. Where and how are you writing the file?

You don't have to add `\n` explicitly to have newlines. As lenik mentioned, you can use `print(arg,file=file_obj)` function (Python 3) `from __future__ import print_function` (Python 2) with file object as a parameter to write to the file. `print` will take care of appending new lines. Or if you absolutely need to have the strings appended to the list, you can iterate or use `"\n".join(list)` then write it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The '\n' character is called an escape sequence character. It represents a new line.
If a string has a '\n' in it, when you look at it, it will have a '\n', but, when you print it, it will appear as a newline. Here is an example:

```
>>> a = '123\n456'
>>> a
'123\n456'
>>> print(a)
123
456
>>>
```

Similarly, there are other escape sequence characters. A backslash is used because, in general, they cannot be directly represented in a string.

\t -> tab

\s -> space

\r -> return

\v -> vertical tab

\' -> '

\" -> "

among others.

In a string, if you want to use a ' or a ", it may terminate the string. Thus, you use \' or \" respectively to represent them.